# Passar o input da busca para outro arquivo

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estou fazendo um projeto de cadastro de automóveis, ele está quase no final, mas ao alterar um pouco o arquivo de estilos e mexer na listagem para deixar em AJAX sem refresh um `bug` estranho aconteceu, já tentei diversas maneiras de resolver: o `input` onde pode ser digitado uma palavra para pesquisa não envia o dado de forma alguma para onde a função deveria pega-lo e mostrar apenas os dados que apresentam a palavra.

Segue o código:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" style="top:12%; left:13px; position:absolute; width:50%" name="frmBusca" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?m=listar" >
    <input type="text" name="palavra" id="palavra     "placeholder="Pesquisar"class="text_busca" />
    <input type="submit" id="buscar" class="btn_busca" value="Buscar" onClick="listar()" />
</form>
```

Função listar do JS:

```
function listar(){
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/teste/services/automoveis.service.php?m=listar",
        type:'post',
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
function mostra(){  
    $palavra = '';
    if(isset($_POST['palavra'])){
        $palavra = $_POST['palavra'];
    }
    $banco = "automoveis";

    $conexao = conecta();
    if($conexao){
        $db=mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco);
    } else {
        echo ("Erro ao conectar ao bando de dados");
        return false;
    }

    echo $palavra;
    $String = "SELECT descricao,placa,codigoRenavam,anoModelo,anoFabricacao,cor,km,marca,preco,precoFipe, id FROM automovel ";
    if($palavra != ''){
        $String .= "WHERE descricao LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR placa LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR codigoRenavam LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR anoModelo LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR anoFabricacao LIKE '%".$palavra."%'
OR cor LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR km LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR marca LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR preco LIKE  '%".$palavra."%' OR precoFipe LIKE  '%".$palavra."%' ";
    }
    $String .= "ORDER BY descricao ";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, $String);
    $ar_info = array();
    while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        error_log(print_r($exibe, true));
        $ar_info[] = $exibe;
    }
    echo json_encode($ar_info);

}
```

O que eu já tentei:

Adicionar esse código da pagina do HTML em uma tag script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >    
    $("#buscar").click(function(){
        var palavra = $("#palavra").serialize();
        console.log(palavra);
        if( $("#palavra").val() != '') {
            console.log($("#palavra").val())
        }
    });
</script>
```

Adicionar na função listar :

```
var palavra = document.getElementById('palavra');
```

Fazendo ela ficar assim:

```
function listar(){
    var palavra = document.getElementById('palavra');
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/teste/services/automoveis.service.php?m=listar",
        type:'post',
        data: palavra,
    });
}
```

Comment: Voce definiu dentro do seu  form o botão submit apontando para a mesma página. Sendo assim, seu form irá chamar a mesma pagina no meio da execução do seu JS, e como JS roda do lado client, ele irá parar a execução. Tente trocar para $('form').submit() ou troque seu botão type de submit para button

Comment: Outra coisa. O caminho do diretorio /teste/services/automoveis.service.php?m=listar é diferente de teste/services/automoveis.service.php?m=listar. Ele está tentando buscar o diretorio teste dentro do diretorio raiz do seu SO. Provavelmente fora do seu diretorio que o apache le. Está correto isso?

Comment: Bruno, obrigada pela resposta, tentei de ambas as formas mas nenhuma resolveu. Quanto a url, ela está funcionando em todas as outras funções, criei ela na raiz, fora de um workspace padrão do eclipse. criei como /www/var/teste

Comment: Tente tirar o method e action que são declarados duplicados no seu form

Comment: Depois do data, tente inserir `success: function(data) {alert(data);}, error: function (error) { alert('deu erro');}` se cair no alert "deu erro" tem algo errado no seu php, se caiu no success é pq nao tem nada errado no seu php

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o action do form vai ser executado primeiro que sua função javascript.

Segue um exemplo funcionando da forma que você quer na pergunta:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("form").submit(function(event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'retornaConsulta.php',
                        data: $(this).serializeArray(), // pega os dados de todos os inputs do formulario
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'post',
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            alert("antes de enviar a requisição ajax");
                        },
                        success: function(retorno) {
                            if (retorno.success) {
                                alert("CONTEUDO PESQUISADO: " + retorno.conteudoPesquisado);
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("NENHUM REGISTRO ENCONTRADO!");
                            }

                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            alert("depois de enviar a requisição ajax");
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("ocorreu algum erro ao enviar a requisição ajax");
                        }
                    });

                    // necessário para não executar o action do formulario
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="pesquisa" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

retornoConsulta.php

```
<?php

$conteudoParaPesquisa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "pesquisa", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// Aqui vai toda sua lógica

// Dados que você vai retornar para seu ajax
echo json_encode(array("success" => "true", "conteudoPesquisado" => $conteudoParaPesquisa));
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido pessoal, muito obrigada pela ajuda. Acabei resolvendo de uma forma um tanto diferente:

HTML:

```
 <form class="frmBus" style="width:50%" name="frmBusca">
     <input type="text" name="palavra" id="palavra" placeholder="Pesquisar" class="text_busca" />
     <input type="button" id="buscar" class="btn_busca" value="Buscar" onClick="listar()" /> 
 </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function listar(){
     var palavra = $("#palavra").val();
     request = $.ajax({
     url: "/teste/services/automoveis.service.php?m=listar",
     type:'post',
     data: "palavra=" + palavra
 });

 request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
     console.log(response);
     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
     getList(obj);
 });

}
```